# How should I bootstrap my web app?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I am looking for the best way to bootstrap my web app using `Backbone.Marionette`, `Backbone.Router` and `Requirejs`.
The following implementation works but I would like to know if this is the right way to make things.

Here's some of my code (*).

My questions are:
1) Is right the following data flow (`index.html` -> `conf.js` -> `router.js` -> `app.js`) ?
2) The `Backbone.View` for each region (`header`, `sidebar` .....) should be instantiate in `router.js` or `app.js` or booths according the context?

---

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Load the script "/js/conf.js" as our entry point -->
        <script data-main="js/conf" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
```

```
// js/config.js
require.config({
    // some code
});
require(['app']);  // instead of  require(['conf']);
```

---

```
// router.js
define([
    'app',
    // others modules
],
function(App, $, _, Backbone, Marionette){
    "use strict";
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        routes: {
            test: test,
            "*defaults": "home"
        }

    var initialize = function ()
    {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

---

```
// js/app.js
define(
[
    // some modules
],
function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Mustache, Layout, SidebarView) {
    var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addInitializer(function () {
        $('body').html(Layout);
        MyApp.addRegions({
            header: '#header',
            sidebar: '#sidebar',
            mainColumn: '#main-column',
            rightColumn: '#right-column'
        });
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function () {
        var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
        MyApp.sidebar.show(sidebarView);
    });

    MyApp.on("initialize:after", function () {
//        Router.initialize();
    });

    MyApp.start();

    return MyApp;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty good overall. There are a few things I might change, but these are mostly personal preferences:

1) Invert the relationship between the router and app files, and use an initializer to start the router.

Right now you have a circular dependency between the router and the app files, and that's never a good thing. Even though RequireJS can handle that fine, it's a bad idea in many other ways as it can lead to code that doesn't quite work the way you expect.

2) In your router file, set up an initializer that instantiates the router.

3) Don't start backbone.history from the router file.

It's common, and suggested, to have multiple routers in a project. But you can only call `Backbone.History.start()` once. Start that in the app.js file, using the "after:initialize" event of the router

`MyApp.on("after:initialize", function(){ Backbone.History.start(); }`

4) Extract your initializer callbacks in to functions that are called from a single initializer

While there's nothing technically wrong with using multiple initializers - and you will need multiple initializers across multiple modules - I suggest using a single initializer within a single module, and have that one initializer call other functions defined in your module.

5) Call `addRegions` outside of initializers

There's no guarantee that your initializers will run in the order you add them. It depends on how the individual browser handles things.

---

For example, your app.js file could look like this:

```
// js/app.js
define(
[
    // some modules
],
function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Mustache, Layout, SidebarView) {
    var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
        header: '#header',
        sidebar: '#sidebar',
        mainColumn: '#main-column',
        rightColumn: '#right-column'
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(){
       showLayout();
       initSidebar();
    });

    MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
      Backbone.History.start();
    });

    function initSidebar() {
        var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
        MyApp.sidebar.show(sidebarView);
    }

    function showLayout() {
        $('body').html(Layout);
    }

    MyApp.start();

    return MyApp;

});
```

...

alright, that looks like a lot more changes than I originally thought. :) But like I said, your set up looks fine over all. These are things that I would do, but are not necessarily requirements to make your app work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed my `conf.js` and `router.js` in my question accordingly to your answer. Just two things not clear: 
1) should I put the `Router.initialize()` somewhere in my app.js (where is the best place) ? 2) If I invert the order `app.js` and then router.js, how can I access MyApp from `router.js`?

Comment: right... scrap inverting the relationship in your case. i don't put routers in separate modules. i always put them in the module that the router is related to.

Comment: ok but if I would like to invert the relationship, because to me it seems more obvious having conf.js -> app.js -> require.js, what should I do?